# statement that executing code over and over

Tags: python, if-statement

I do not know how to do code that is executing over and over again. I would like to achieve something like this:
(< stands for input, > stands for output)

```
message=input()
print('Write down the text.')
```

```
>Write down the text.
<qwerty
>qwerty
>Write down the text.
<asd
>asd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
while True:
   message=input("Write down the text: ")
   print(message)
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate that, I couldn't find out how to do it for a month

Comment: @ApocalypseNow Could you mark this answer as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a

```
   while True:
      // code you want to execute repeatedly here
```

The while loop will continue to execute until the condition becomes false (which it never will, in this case) so if/when you want to break out of the loop you'll need to have use a `break` statement

Comment: When I enter it, the text that I've entered is being written over and over. I want to be able to give one input then next and next... but without process finishing.